# Jupyter ipywidgets box not resizing after content change

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets

I'm trying to set the number of inputs in a section to match a slider. This works fine until I try to have the box resize to the number of inputs. If I hide one of the inputs with a button instead it works fine.

I have a widget setup that allows collapsing sections with a button:

```py
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets
button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
output = widgets.Output()

label = widgets.Label("hello")
inputs = [
    widgets.Label("A"),
    widgets.Label("B"),
    widgets.Label("C"),
    widgets.Label("D"),
]
section = widgets.VBox(inputs)
def on_button_clicked(b):
    inputs[2].layout.visibility = 'visible' if inputs[2].layout.visibility == 'hidden' else 'hidden'
    inputs[2].layout.height = '0' if inputs[2].layout.visibility == 'hidden' else 'auto'
    
button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
display(widgets.Box([label, button, section]))
display(output)
```

But when using a slider instead it does not expand the box to fit the inputs:

```py
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets

inputs = [widgets.Text() for _ in range(10)]
field_count = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=len(inputs)-1)
input_container = widgets.VBox(inputs)

def limit_inputs_to_slider(sender):
    for i, inputItem in enumerate(inputs):
        if i > field_count.value:
            inputItem.layout.visibility = "hidden"
            inputItem.layout.max_height = "0"
        else:
            inputItem.layout.visibility = "visible"
            inputItem.layout.max_height = "100"

field_count.observe(limit_inputs_to_slider, names="value")

display(field_count)
display(input_container)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting specifying `px` in the max height value.
`inputItem.layout.max_height = "0"` and `inputItem.layout.max_height = "100px"`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work if the default height should be auto